# How to send HTTP POST to GCM using AS3 (google cloud messaging for android)

Tags: actionscript-3, http, air, google-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to make the HTTP request to GCM from actionscript in my AIR ANDROID app. What am I doing wrong? I'm following the request [format here](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html#server).

I keep getting an error 400 back

```
var url:String = "https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send";

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url);

var rhArray:Array = new Array(new URLRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"),new URLRequestHeader("Authorization", "key=MYAPIKEY"));
            request.requestHeaders = rhArray;

var msgData:String = JSON.stringify({"message":"holy crap message worked","title":"the message title here"});
var postData:String = JSON.stringify({"registration_ids":["THELONGREGISTRATIONIDOFTHEDEVICEIWANTTOMESSAGE"],"data":msgData});

request.data = postData;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
urlLoader = new URLLoader();

urlLoader.addEventListener(HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_STATUS, httpStatusHandler, false, 0, true);
urlLoader.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler, false, 0, true);

urlLoader.load(request);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a 401 HTTP status code, your API key is not valid.
So assuming you have a valid API key, the first thing you have to fix is to change

```
"Authorization", "MYAPIKEY"
```

to

```
"Authorization", "key=MYAPIKEY"
```

If you receive a 400 HTTP status code, your JSON is invalid.
Make sure that it looks like this :

```
{ "collapse_key": "score_update",
  "time_to_live": 108,
  "delay_while_idle": true,
  "data": {
    "score": "4x8",
    "time": "15:16.2342"
  },
  "registration_ids":["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

You might be missing some quotes (it looks like your keys don't have quotes).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Unfortunately as you posted your answer, I was just updating my question. I had just saw that key= needed to be added. It's still not working. I'm getting a 400 error now. But with no other information in the event object. Happen to have any other ideas?

Comment: I just updated above to show eactly how I have it. Since im just sending to 1 registration id i have ["THELONGID"]. Also, I noticed if i trace out my string. It has a lot of slashes before the quotes like `\"` Should I stop that somehow?

Comment: Can you print your postData variable? From your code above, it looks like you don't quote your keys (data should be "data", registration_ids should be "registration_ids", etc...)

Comment: I went ahead and tried what you suggested, but still no luck. I just didn't have those because I thought that's what `JSON.stringify` was for. Even with the added quotes still get the same response.

Comment: @brybam Well, if you print your JSON (the postDataariable) I'll be able to tell you where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I also had trouble getting past the 400 HTTP status code. I tried implementing the functionality with the code from brybam, and as stated in the answer, the 400 code means that the JSON part of the http request is invalid.

Replace these two lines from brybam's first post:

`var msgData:String = JSON.stringify({"message":"holy crap message worked","title":"the message title here"});`

`var postData:String = JSON.stringify({"registration_ids":["THELONGREGISTRATIONIDOFTHEDEVICEIWANTTOMESSAGE"],"data":msgData});`

With these:

`var msgData:String = JSON.stringify({data:{message:"holy crap message worked",title:"the message title here"}});`

`var postData:String = JSON.stringify({registration_ids:["THELONGREGISTRATIONIDOFTHEDEVICEIWANTTOMESSAGE"]});`

`// remove the first curly bracket of msgData since we will concatenate the two strings in a moment.`

`msgData = msgData.slice(1,msgData.length);`

`// remove the last curly bracket of postData too.`

`postData = postData.slice(0, postData.length-1);`

`// concatenate the two, separated by a comma.`

`postData = postData.concat(",",msgData);`

That worked for me, if you trace out the postData variable, you will see that the JSON is now correctly formatted.
Cheers, Claus